# How to make a server read the latest msg from a topic?

Tags: ros, msg-subscriber, topics

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Greetings,
All I want to do is for my server to take a the latest msg from a topic and return it. The service server would take no inputs and return one output. Eg: Return robot position. Or Return a map.

I made a service server node. In the callback of the service I had the node subscribe to the topic I want. In the line were the service node subscribes to the topic, I expect the latest msg to be obtained right then and there from the topic because I made the topic latched by setting the latch argument to True. But it doesn't do as expected. As you can see from the code below I am forced to include the wait_for_message or else the server node never reads a msg.
The topic I am subscribed to doesn't publish frequently and waiting for a message is not practical, I just want the service to return the latest msg on the topic without waiting for the next one, I thought having the topic latched would take care of that. But it didn't.

Thank you

```
globvar = 0
def callback(msg_arg): # subscription callback 
    global globvar
    print "in sub cb ",globvar
    globvar = int(float(msg_arg.data)) #because you cant int(float_string)

def service_callback(req): # service callback
    print "in server cb "
    sb = rospy.Subscriber('chatter', String, callback)
    rospy.wait_for_message("chatter", String)
    global globvar
    print (globvar)
    sb.unregister()
    return globvar
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/276202/how-to-make-a-server-read-the-latest-msg-from-a-topic?/) by [RobotWhisperer](https://answers.ros.org/users/32016/robotwhisperer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2017-11-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The best way to implement something like this is `rospy.wait_for_message(..)`. Creating `Subscriber`s in callbacks is not a good idea.

If you're really only interested in a single message (which happens to be 'the last' only because of latching) then don't create the `Subscriber`, but use `rospy.wait_for_message(..)` only.

Note btw that what you show in your question text is really brittle: there is no way to guarantee that `globvar` will contain an actual message object at that point.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-11-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-11-17**:
It will also let you avoid all those ugly `global` vars.

**Comment by [RobotWhisperer](https://answers.ros.org/users/32016/robotwhisperer/) on 2017-11-18**:
Perfect. I didn't know I can use wait_for_message without subscribing. And I also didn't know that wait_for_message actually returns the message. My code is more robust now and doesn't have global variable. Thank you.